# Are UK visas granted to travel to the UK usable elsewhere?

Tags: visas, uk, british-virgin-islands, mongolian-citizens

I am a Mongolian citizen currently in England on a one year visa.  Can I travel to British Virgin Islands, or other Caribbean islands that require a British visa using the visa I have for the UK, or do I need a separate visa for each country or island I visit?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters, but maybe it would help to state specifically what type of UK visa you currently have?

Comment: In some cases a UK visa will work for the BVI. But as @NateEldredge says, a definitive answer will require lots more info.

Comment: To clarify further, my 9 year old son, an American citizen, has a one year U.K. student visa and is attending school in London.  I am a Mongolian citizen and was granted a one year U.K. visa  as a guardian parent.  During the winter vacation, we would like to travel on a cruise, or fly directly to the Virgin islands, or San Maarten, for example, or another British territory where it's warm in the winter.  I know my son can travel to any of those places.  The question is which places in the Carribbean would I be able to travel to without the hassles of applying for a separate visa.